# AngularJS ng-repeat not tracking deep changes in model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a model object in a controller, which I want to repeat with certain HTML. The model object consists of multiple '**key**', '**value**' pairs which are dynamically added and the '**value**' part is an array. But, whenever I try to dynamically push items into the '**value**' array of any key in the model object, the '**ng-repeat**' doesn't update. Can anyone give me a solution to this, if I'm implementing it in a wrong way, please suggest the changes as well. But I would prefer the model object remain the same.

```
var myCtrl = function($scope) {
   $scope.myModelObject = {};
   $scope.addToModelObject = function(key, value) {
      if($scope.myModelObject[key] == undefined) {
         $scope.myModelObject[key] = [];
      }
      $scope.myModelObject[key].push(value);
   }
}

myCtrl['$inject'] = ['$scope'];

<li ng-repeat="(key, value) in myModelObject"><!-- my html goes here --></li>
```

I use addToModelObject() function to add to the model object dynamically.

Comment: Can you post a code example or a JSFiddle?

Comment: I'd suggest you added a fiddle/plunk to make your question clear.

Comment: I suspect if you're pushing the values into the original array or a clone of it. As you said, _'value' part is an array_ most probably you used `.splice()` method which clones original array.

Comment: Try to reproduce your problem here: http://plnkr.co/edit/aKLYIX6VZPzpxqjmkFhZ?p=preview

Comment: It got solved I'd typed $scope.myModelObject = []; instead of $scope.myModelObject = {}; in the controller which I completely ignored. Sorry for the negligence guys and thanks for your comments.